# String with specific pattern to Date in java

Tags: java, date, duration

I have a string which comes from an API and it gives me the duration of a trip.

- Sometimes it is look like this : `PT5H27M`
- sometimes it is like : `PT5H`
- and sometimes it is like : `PT27M`

I would like to get a `Date` variable from this.

I wrote some function by using pattern and matcher but it takes too long when my list of trips are long.
Would you suggest me a better way.
I attached my code in the following:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("PT(\\d*)H*(\\d*)M*");
private long getDurationOfTrip(Pattern pattern,String duration){
    long durationOfTrip = 0 ;
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(duration);

    if (m.find()){
        if (duration.contains("H")&&duration.contains("M"))
            durationOfTrip =  (Long.parseLong(m.group(1))*60) + Long.parseLong(m.group(2));
        else if (duration.contains("H")&& !duration.contains("M"))
            durationOfTrip =  (Long.parseLong(m.group(1))*60);
        else
            durationOfTrip = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
    }

    return durationOfTrip;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These strings (such as `PT5H27M`) represent a [duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), which is **not** a date:

- a date represents a specific point in some calendar system, such as **"March 25th 2017 at 10 AM"**
- a duration represents an amount of intervening time, such as **"5 hours and 27 minutes"**

While a date represents a specific moment, a duration is not attached to any calendar system at all (5 hours and 27 minutes relative to what moment? it doesn't matter, it's just an **amount of time**).

Treating durations as dates *might* work sometimes, but you shouldn't, because those are different concepts (although related, but they're not the same thing).

Anyway, in Java 8 or higher, just use the `java.time.Duration` class to parse the string, and then use one of the `toXXX` methods to get the total duration in terms of whatever unit you want (in your case, you're calculating the total number of minutes, so use the `toMinutes` method):

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse("PT5H27M");

// get the total number of minutes (in this case, 327)
long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
```

In Java 7 or lower, you can use the [Threeten Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/):  (it contains classes with the same names and functionality).

Comment: If he really wants a `Date` from his `Duration`, he will have to create a new `Date` based on the starting time of the trip, and pass the duration in milliseconds or some similar TimeUnit to a new instance of `Date`.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer With `java.time` API, you can also do `start.plus(duration)` - assuming that `start` is one of the `java.time`'s types (such as `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, etc). But you're right, adding a duration to a date results in another date.

Answer (score 1):

About regex, may be shorter using slightly modified pattern `PT(?:(\\d+)H)?(?:(\\d+)M)?` and custom parseLong function

```
static long parseLong( String s ) {
    return s == null || "".equals( s ) ? 0 : Long.parseLong( s );
}

static long getDurationOfTrip( Pattern pattern, String duration ) {
    long durationOfTrip = 0;
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher( duration );
    if ( m.find() ) {
        return parseLong( m.group( 1 ) ) * 60 + parseLong( m.group( 2 ) );
    }
    return durationOfTrip;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I changed my code with your code but it still takes time on long list of trips.Any way thanks for your help.
I would be grateful if you also give more details about the pattern your wrote.